# How to call default implementation of heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone

In my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method I want to customize height only for certain rows. For the rest I want the framework to take care. How would I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can just return `tableView.rowHeight`, which is set to a default value unless you change it.

Answer (score 8):

Return the constant `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Available since iOS 5.0, [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UITableViewAutomaticDimension).